Help with PSD graph interpretation and Time Series Analysis
I am pretty new to time series analysis and I am currently studying it. My latest work requires me to work with a time series that was generate by VASP AIMD. I tried power spectrum density analysis and ARMA modeling but got no luck. I was wondering if anyone has insights or have worked a similar problem before.
I tried to upload some of the image but I can't for some reason.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
